# Intuitively predict the direction of the acceleration vector of a single parameter vector valued function

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, physics

The velocity vector of a Vector valued function (or position function), (for example $f(t)= \lt x(t),y(t) \gt$)
 seems to always be tangent to the curve of motion, its pretty intuitive why that is.

However intuition about what the acceleration vector $f ^{\prime \prime}(t)$ looks like or where does it point is hard to find.

Can I somehow predict or get an intuition on what the acceleration vector might be or where does it point to? how?.

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration vector is not uniquely determined by the curve, it depends on the way it is parametrized.  However, when the curve is parametrized by it's arclength, the acceleration vector of the curve is perpendicular to the velocity vector in 2 dimensions. In higher dimensions, this is no longer true.

The arclength of a curve is given by $s=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}$, where $t$ is any given parametrization. If the curve is given by $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ and it's arclength parametrization is $r(s)=(X(s), Y(s))$ then

$$\hat{T}(s)=\Big(\frac{dX}{ds}, \frac{dY}{ds}\Big)=\frac{dr}{ds}=\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{dt}{ds}=\Big(\frac{x'(t)}{\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}},\frac{y'(t)}{\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}}\Big)$$

and we conclude that

$$||\hat{T}(s)||=1$$

Now are allowed to write $\frac{dX}{ds}=\cos\theta(s),\frac{dY}{ds}=\sin\theta(s)$

and the acceleration of the curve can be written as

$$a(s)=\frac{dT(s)}{ds}=\theta'(s)(-\sin\theta, \cos\theta)=\frac{d\theta}{ds}\hat{n}$$

and it's easy to show that $T\cdot \hat{n}=0$ and thus the acceleration is perpendicular to the velocity in this case.

If the curve is parametrized by any other parameter, the direction of the acceleration is not perpendicular to the tangent vector anymore, since we can write $\frac{dx}{dt}=||v(t)||\cos\theta(t), \frac{dy}{dt}=||v(t)||\sin\theta(t)$ and thus

$$a(t)=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{d||v||}{dt}(\cos\theta(t), \sin\theta(t))+||v||\frac{d\theta}{dt}(-\sin\theta(t), \cos\theta(t))=\frac{d||v||}{dt}\hat{T}+||v||\frac{d\theta}{dt}\hat{n}$$

which shows that the acceleration now has a component in the tangent direction as well, which is zero if $t=s$.

EDIT: In Newtonian physics, the trajectory of the particle is determined by the equation of motion $m\frac{d^2r(t)}{dt^2}=F$. In this case it is clear that this equation determines the direction of the acceleration of the particle, and the acceleration is not necessarily the same as the geometrical acceleration of the curve. In other words, the time parameter $t$ has a physical meaning and it's relationship to the arclength $s=s(t)$ is determined by the equations of motion and it's not chosen freely, like in differential geometry. One has to solve the equations of motion to be able to tell the relationship between the curve and the body's acceleration. However, the last equation written above for $a(t)$ is correct, and it represents the decomposition of the particle's acceleration to tangential and normal components.

Comment: I chose to speak about the mathematical definition of the acceleration, not the physical definition of acceleration. In physics, the relationship between arclength and time is determined by the equations of motion, but in differential geometry the object of interest is the geometrical curve so this has reparametrization invariance.

Comment: Edited to reflect the physical relation within the paradigm of Newtonian physics of a particle's acceleration to it's trajectory.

Comment: In 3-space, the velocity vector and the acceleration vector are not necessarily orthogonal, even if they are paramerized by the arc length. The acceleration vector is a= d(dr/ds)/ds  The unit tangent vector is T=(dr/ds)/||dr/ds||. The principal  normal vector is N=(dT/ds)/||dT/ds||. The vectors v and T, which are in the same direction, are orthogonal to the vectors dT/ds and N, which are in the same direction.  The vector a is not necessarily in the same direction as N, nor is it necessarily perpendicular to v.Exercise: Work out these vectors for x=t, y=t^2,z=t^3 and check these assertions.

Comment: @P.Lawrence the curve you are quoting is not parametrized in terms of arclength, or in 2-D like the problem states. In the question it is stated that $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$.

Comment: (i)You can obtain results for a parametrization with respect to arc length s  from a parametrization in terms of t without explicitly giving the parametrization  in terms of s, e.g. dx/ds =(dx/dt)/(ds/dt). (ii) the question title did not have a restriction to 2-space (iii) I do not dispute (or agree) that the velocity vector and the acceleration vector are orthogonal in 2-space (iv) It is important to note that in 3-space there is an important formula a=s ^{..}T+(s^.)^2\kappa N where \kappa is the cuvature. There is, in general, no reason for the tangential component ,s double dot, to be 0.

Comment: The question did not specify that the curve was parametrized in terms of arc length. Yes, whether we are in 2-space or 3-space,it is true that, if s=t, then ds/dt =1, d(ds/dt)/dt=0 and a=scalar multiple of N, i.e. the acceleration vector is in the direction of the normal vector N, so a is orthogonal to T. But I see no reason to resrict ourselves to such parametrizations.Indeed, (i) it is often difficult or impossible to write such a parametrization explicitly (ii) in many applications e.g. highway engineering, "ds/dt=1" is artificial or unrealistic.

Comment: Could you clarify what are the functions being derivated at $\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{dt}{ds}$? I'm more familiar with the prime notation, I'm finding lebnitz notation a bit confusing on this case.