# Eyeballing direction of acceleration in curve of fuction from $\Bbb R^1$ to $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, vector-analysis, intuition

This question emanates directly from [This previous question I made](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607231/intuitively-predict-the-direction-of-the-acceleration-vector-of-a-single-paramet/3607265#3607265), but from a more general perspective.

Given some function $f(t)\colon \mathbb{R^1}\to\mathbb{R^n}$  parametrized in some arbitrary way that draws some curve, can I eyeball the acceleration from the curve? can I at least eyeball where the acceleration would NOT point to?

For example, the following curve in RED is the image of some function $f(t)\colon \mathbb{R^1}\to\mathbb{R^2}$. The velocity is marked in ORANGE at some point and is tangent to the curve (that we already know). The purple lines indicate possible acceleration vectors for that curve in that point.

[image]

**The question:**

> Given only the image of the function (the curve). Are all the purple acceleration vectors equally possible? 
>   Can I discard some general direction? Why?

Here I'm interested only in direction, since I understand that the magnitude is impossible to infer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant formula you want is this: If $\upsilon$ is the speed of the particle, then

$$\vec a = \upsilon’ \vec T + \kappa\upsilon^2 \vec N,$$

where $\vec T$ and $\vec N$ are the unit tangent and principal normal, respectively. It follows that the acceleration vector must be in the half-plane determined by the tangent line and the principal normal. (To derive this, differentiate $\upsilon\vec T$ with respect to time.)

Comment: In this case that would be below the dotted pink line on the drawing?. That was what my gut was telling me. I will need to study this formula further and come back later.

Comment: Yes, Joaquin. Precisely. If you haven't seen this formula (in physics, for example) you should derive it. Also, check out my differential geometry text (linked in my profile) sometime, if you're interested. This is in there.

Comment: Haven't seen it, I'm a self learner and I havent seen physics with calculus yet. Actually I was following a multivariable calculus course and "got lost" on my way, somehow ended on differential geometry hahaha. Thanks I will check out your texts.

Comment: Ted, Would you be so kind to tell me in what courses one would encounter applications to these topics on differential geometry? I would love to have a look at those.

Comment: Sorry, Joaquin. I'm not quite sure what you’re asking. After multivariable calculus and some linear algebra, a course like my differential geometry text should be accessible to you.

Comment: Let me rephrase, You mentioned that this formula might be seen in physics, which is a discipline that applies math to the real world but is not a math course in itself. What is the name of the physics course/s you had in mind when you said that?. Im interested to peek into the applications of this in other fields like physics and the like.

Comment: This appears just a standard (calculus-based) mechanics course. It's related to centripetal acceleration in the case of (uniform) circular motion.

Comment: In the plane $a$ will point to the inward side of the curve -- the angle it makes with $v$ depends on how the speed is changing. If the speed is constant then $a$ and $v$ are orthogonal; if  speed is increasing, then the angle is acute.